# Клиент не пингуется по домену, но пингуется по IP

Tags: windows-server-2012

Разбираюсь с администрированием Windows Server 2012, столкнулась с проблемой:

`ping 192.168.5.2 (присвоенный DHCP сервером ip)` пингует

`ping client1.example.com (имя компа+домен сервера)` не пингует

при этом проходит пинг

`ping example.com` по домену сервера

`ping client1` по имени клиента

Правда, когда пингую только по имени компа, он добавляет в конце .local

Что я делаю не так, куда смотреть, почему возникла такая проблема?
Сервер развернут на виртуалке VMWare.

Comment: смотреть записи в dns, проверить сам сервер, в каком домене

Comment: .local - значит не в домене

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась самым простым и глупым образом
Нужно было просто в свойствах DHCP-сервера выбрать "Всегда динамически обновлять DNS-записи", по умолчанию обновлялось только по запросу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]